# Implementation on atoi() function with base

Tags: c

I'm going a bit mad implementing this function. I think I have narrow the algorithm down but I have some strange behavior for some value. It seems to work for most of the values and bases, but for string "1000" it simply returns 0.

Below the code:

```
// A C program for 
// implementation of atoi 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
int val(char c) 
{ 
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') 
        return (int)c - '0'; 
    else
        return (int)c - 'A' + 10; 
} 
int32_t my_atoi(uint8_t * ptr, uint8_t digits, uint32_t base){
    // Initialize result 
    digits = 0; 
    // Initialize sign as positive 
    int sign = 1; 
    // Initialize index of first digit 
    int i = 0; 
    // If number is negative, 
    // then update sign 
    if (*ptr == '-') { 
        sign = -1; 
        i++; 
    }
    // Iterate through all digits and update the result 
    for (; *(ptr+i) != '\0'; ++i){ 
        digits = (digits * base) + val(*(ptr+i));
        printf("Digits of %d is:%d\n",i,digits);  
    }
    // Return result with sign 
    return sign * digits; 
} 
// Driver program to test above functions 
int main() 
{ 
    uint8_t str[] = "1000";
    uint8_t val2=0; 
    int val = my_atoi(str, val2, 16); 
    printf("%d \n", val); 
    return 0; 
}
```

For the above code the output is:

```
Digits of 0 is:1
Digits of 1 is:16
Digits of 2 is:0
Digits of 3 is:0
0
```

I simply cannot understand why digits becomes 0 after it has the value 16.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you pass in `digits`, and why is it an 8-bit value?

Comment: Do you know what `UINT8_MAX` is?

Comment: _Side note:_ Why is `digits` an argument at all [and it should be the same as the return type--`int32_t`]? It serves no [discernible] purpose as written--unless you are trying to accumulate a larger number from _multiple_ calls. But, this could be done via: `tot += my_atoi(str,16);` Are you trying to implement `strtol` that takes a `char **` to return the end pointer of `str` to the caller?

Comment: @CodyGray: This does not look like a duplicate of those. Those questions address **what** happens when a result is out of bounds. The problem in this question arises because OP either did not know or failed to recognize either **when** a result was out of bounds or what the bounds were. It is certainly a very elementary computer science issue that an eight-bit unsigned binary integer can only represent numbers up to 255, but it is nonetheless a very different question from what a compiler does or what a language standard says to do when a result is out of bounds.

Comment: @Eric The very first question in the list explains exactly what happens here and gives sufficient information to solve the problem.

Comment: @CodyGray: Again, the question here is not **what** happens. It is **when** it happens. The fact that the first question in the list explains what happens is irrelevant; it is not explaining when it happens, so it is not answering this question.

Comment: @CodyGray: In either words, the problem here appears to be that OP did not know the `uint8_t` type was for an eight-bit unsigned binary numeral, or they did not know what the limits of an eight-bit unsigned binary numeral were, or they knew but overlooked that their `digits` was such a type, or something along those lines. The issue is not that, when overflow occurs, the result is wrapped. The issue is that OP did not recognize that overflow was occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `digits` is a `uint8_t` so it just overflows to 0. You should make it a larger, signed, data type like `int32_t` or `int64_t` so the sign works properly and it doesn't overflow.